# Migrating from ASP.NET 4 to .NET CORE 1.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-middleware

I'm working on migrating from ASP.NET 4/Webforms to ASP.NET Core/MVC. I'm new to MVC, but understand the concept. I have, however, ran into one issue with getting the handle on ASP.NET Core. I have several questions.

With my legacy (ASPNET4) projects, I wrote a "helper" library that provides basic functions for my web projects: 
 - Database Handling (connection, cleanup, error catching, caching, paging, binding, etc)

- Misc functions (viewstate compression, date/time functions, etc)
- Storage management (Sessions, cookies, etc)
- Plugins (twitter, facebook, google integrations)
- Identity Management (custom identity that works with other systems)
- I think you get the point...

Over the years, I have developed this framework while constantly updating and bug fixing. It has become very fast and stable - it even handles any database you want to throw at it!

While researching, I found that .NET Core makes it hard for me to accomplish the same tasks. First off, it seems like CORE only supports object relational mappers (entity, dapper, etc). I'm perfectly content with ADO.NET, and understand the differences. I just really don't want to use the Entity Framework, or Dapper. I can migrate most of my code from .NET Framework. But it looks like ADO.NET isn't fully supported in .NET Core. Is this the case?

My next issue comes along after database support. I'm finding it incredibility difficult to manage things like sessions/cookies/etc from a class library. Perhaps I am misunderstanding the concepts, or not finding the proper documentation, but it appears as if it is nearly impossible to manage Session/Cache/etc in an external library. Is this the case? Or do I need to research creating custom middleware?

Basically, I need full access to the website from a library so I can use my own code to handle things like Sessions, data management, etc.

Is MVC the only option available for ASP.NET?

Finally, it seems like Visual Studio 2015 is very glitchy and slow with handling .NET Core applications. This has been a major turn off for me, everything from the interface to NuGet seems slow and glitchy.

Any recommendations or suggestions on where I should go or start with .NET core is greatly appreciated, I've spent weeks reading documentation and experimenting but have made no real progress. I really want to move away from webforms!

Answer (score 1):

Next Tuesday (3/7/17) Visual Studio 2017 will release, which has fully integrated support for .NET Core. VS15 has the preview tooling right now, which causes a lot of the glitches you are experiencing. You might also want to consider converting over to the VS17 RC right now if you are early on in the process, as .NET Core 1.1 is much more friendly than 1.0.1 (in my opinion, since there is no project.json).

<strike>As for the database interactions, the idea behind Entity Framework is that it is a drastic improvement over having a DAL or another database service layer on top of your program. Through EF Core's Middleware/DbContext all database interactions can be completed with raw SQL or LINQ (or both). With this interaction, there isn't really a need to have the DAL/ADO layer.</strike>

Entity Framework is built on ADO.NET, and is a drastic improvement over other entity relationship libraries. See mason's comment below on ADO.NET on wikipedia for a better look at this.

As for the cookies/sessions, I'm not terribly experienced with this kind of information, but the one thing you might want to look into is the ASP.NET Identity for user information and sessions. IdentityServer 4 is another option.

Comment: ADO.NET (for the most part) is still in .NET Core. EF is still built on top of it. Have a look at the [source](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design/Internal/SqlServerDatabaseModelFactory.cs).

Comment: Whoops, my terminology is really bad on that stuff. I'll update my answer to have a better usage. Thanks!

Comment: No worries about your terminology. I read a lot of performance reviews of Entity framework, and it didn't impress me. I just prefer ADONET, but I guess I should start the learning process. 

It's good to know that everything is bad because of preview tooling. I have messed with VS17 RC, but it caused issues with VS15. I'm going to give it another go though since that was several months ago. Thanks!